# Oracle Prior Query To SQLite

Tags: oracle, sqlite

I have a query like this

```
SELECT "SOME FIELDS"
FROM (SELECT "SOME FIELDS" FROM WHERE FIELD=VALUE1 AND FIELD=VALUE2)
CONNECT BY **PRIOR** FIELD1=FIELD2  START WITH FIELD=VALUE1
ORDER BY **FIELDS**
```

I have this tutorial but I don't understand it

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/24/sql-server-introduction-to-hierarchical-query-using-a-recursive-cte-a-primer/

Comment: Obfuscating your table and column names does not really help when answer the question.

Comment: I am afraid, SQLite doesn't support CTE (common table expression), and this tutorial is useless.

Comment: @kordirko: yes it does, since 3.8.3: https://sqlite.org/news.html

Comment: i know 4 this but any kind of query that can i use as a prior...nd sry 4 my bad english

Comment: i have use this queries in android devices...so its SQLite version is lower than < 3.8

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you, good to know. This version was released a month ago (2014-02-03) !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle's "connect by" syntax needs to be translated to a recursive common table expression when using other DBMS (that comply with the SQL standard).

SQLite supports recursive CTEs since Version 3.8.3 https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html

Your statement would translate to something like this:

```
with recursive my_tree as (
   select column_1, column_2, column_3
   from your_table 
   where field = value1  --- <<< this is the "start with part" in Oracle

   union all

   select c.column_1, c.column_2, c.column_3
   from your_table c
     join my_tree p           
       on p.field2 = c.field1 -- <<< this is the "prior ..." part in Oracle
) 
select *
from my_tree
order by some_column;
```